# Script for exporting all installed win updates on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, windows-update

This scripts works perfectly fine on single server, but how do I run it on multiple servers?

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Updates = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$HistoryCount)
$Updates | Select Title,@{l='Name';e={$($_.Categories).Name}},Date
```

Comment: I have found below script but how can i make this to work?                               
 $scriptDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
."$scriptDirectory\Get-MSHotfix.ps1" 
$allUpdates = '' 
$array = @("host1", "host2", "host3") 
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) { 
$Updates = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $array[$i] ${function:Get-MSHotfix}|ft -HideTableHeaders 
$allUpdates += $Updates 
} 
$allUpdates

Comment: I get this error: . : The term '\Get-MSHotfix.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ ."$scriptDirectory\Get-MSHotfix.ps1"
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\Get-MSHotfix.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I've been using  'Get-WUHistory -ComputerName $server -Last 1'   If you have PSWindowsUpdate module installed.

Comment: please don't post code in the comments and edit it into your question

Comment: The error indicates that it can't find a ps1 with the name of `Get-MSHotfix.

Answer (score 0):

To stick to your original question, you can get the results for multiple servers using `Invoke-Command` like this:

```
# set the credentials for admin access on the servers
$cred    = Get-Credential 'Please enter your admin credentials'
# create an array of the servers you need to probe
$servers = 'Server01', 'Server02'

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    $Session      = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
    $Searcher     = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
    $Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$HistoryCount) |
        Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Title,
                      @{Name = 'Name';Expression = {$($_.Categories).Name}}, Date

    # make sure you destroy the used COM objects from memory when done
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Searcher)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Session)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}

# remove the extra properties PowerShell added
$result = $result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId

# show on screen
$result | Format-List

# output to csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\updates.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, I will try this and update

Comment: Hi Theo, I tried above but it's not doing anything. script getting executed fine without error. What m I doing wrong here?

Comment: @PrathameshTalaulikar Strange, for me it works. Are you sure you are using admin credentials for the servers?